# Is there a way to get contract address from dapp name?

Tags: contract-invocation, dapps, addresses

I have been looking at [already built and in progress dapps](https://dapps.ethercasts.com/) and some of ones that have been built have their contracts addresses listed that then can be used to [check the earnings on etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/address/0xc150bf564a4f58d72e05544fd253894a0e86c83e)

Most of the apps however do not have it linked in dapps.ethercasts.com,

**Is there a way to get contract address from dapp name?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to get the deployed contract address either

1. The developer explicitly specify it
2. You dig into the code and figure out.

There is something called [ENS](https://ens.domains)

> ENS offers a secure and decentralised way to address resources both on and off the blockchain using simple, human-readable names.

which again require the developer to link to it.

Also, you can look for registered names [etherscan.io/enslookup](https://etherscan.io/enslookup)